# CMake Compilation Flags

Tags: cmake

I'm using CMake in a project of mine, and I would like to use a different set of optimization flags for each file. Some files contain code that I would like to optimize for space and others I would like to optimize for performance.

Is there anyway to do this using CMake? The only way I can currently imagine is using this:

```
set_property(SOURCE ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/bitmap.c APPEND_STRING COMPILE_FLAGS "/Wall /WX /O1")
```

I know there's ways to set the optimization flags for specific files, but will building in release or debug mode have an effect on this? I want to make sure I'm doing this in a way that isn't just some hack, otherwise I might just revert back to Make.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [set_source_file_properties](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.12/cmake.html#command%3aset_source_files_properties) command. Take a look at [all the properties available for source files](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.12/cmake.html#section_PropertiesonSourceFiles) and you will notice a COMPILE_DEFINITIONS and COMPILE_FLAGS property.

Comment: But if you do set a build-type, you can check for that with CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE

Comment: This is an important caveat. One should set CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE to the empty string to avoid accidentally having compile options added.